# Should symlinked programs be put on drives with fast write speeds?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, symbolic-link

When deciding where to symlink-move a program, should it be to a drive that has a fast write speed, in lieu of program's needing to cache/write to disk? OR, if/when a program needs to cache to disk, will it always use the main system (Windows) pagefile?

NOTES

I've been symlinking program folders off my SSD and onto my external to make space on my nearly full SSD. I realized that the write speed of this external drive is pretty slow. Other than the initial symlink-transfer to the drive, would I need to worry about moved programs having to cache/write to this slow external? Or do programs stick to writing to the main system pagefile (or Windows AppData folders, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well written program generally won't be writing to its `Program Files` folder unless you're upgrading / reinstalling. Most programs do their writing to/from various folders in the user's home directory (My Documents, AppData, Temp, etc.). The paging file is wherever you have it configured in windows, and generally applications don't have much control over that.

Comment: Thanks! My pagefile and App/Data folders all reside on the SSD. Out of curiosity -- which gets the bulk of writing to disk from programs -- the pagefile or AppData/Temp folders? (A subjective question, yes, just curious on an average/general level)

Comment: It varies so wildly based upon the type of program that the question can't be answered without more specifics.